# C How can I avoid dereferencing the same variable multiple times?

Tags: c, pointers, c99, dereference

I have an array of structs, and I have some functions that will be using several of the members of those structs. I would like to avoid the dereference in every line. I would think that there would be some way to declare a variable at a certain memory location... something like:

```
someStruct &myStruct = arrayOfStructs[i];
myStruct.x = foo+bar*myStruct.y*myStruct.w;
//Instead of myStruct->x = foo+bar*myStruct->y*myStruct->w;
//It would/should even be possible to access the members in a similar way:
int &x = &myStruct.x;
x = x+4*y+2*z;
//This should avoid overhead of dereferencing the pointer, and offsetting to the member
//by just accessing that particular address of memory as though it was where the variable
//had always been.
```

This bit of example code may help explain:

```
#define NUM_BIGSTRUCTS 10000

typedef struct {
  int a,b,c;
  float d,e,f;
} bigStruct;

bigStruct* arrayOfStructs;

void foo() {
  for(int i=0; i<NUM_BIGSTRUCTS; i++) {
    bigStruct* temp = arrayOfStructs[i];
    temp->f = (temp->d+temp->e)*((float)temp->a+temp->e);
    //more similar, with conditionals, etc...
    //actually I've got nested loops, and a very very large array
    //so any gains per inner loop would decrease my number of instructions exponentially

    //So, if I could declare a bigStruct and set its address to the location of a bigStruct in the array
    //then I could avoid a dereference every time I access a member of that bigStruct
    //Leaving just the member access overhead... which could be handled in a similar manner
    //if possible, and when appropriate
  }
}

int main(int argx, char** argv) {
  arrayOfStructs = g_new0(bigStruct,NUM_BIGSTRUCTS); //Allocate and 0 memory for simplicity

  foo();

  return 0;
}
```

I never have had great success on SO, so hopefully I explained what I'm trying to do. I'm using C99 btw, and I would believe it'd be possible given the low level nature of c.

[edit]
Looks like I was looking for 'References' from C++, but for C. Even so, they only allow assignment once(initialization), which wouldn't work in my example. I've decided to rely on the compiler to optimize away multiple accesses to the same section of memory.

Thanks,
James Newman

Comment: @cnicular I'd argue that there needn't be any overhead at all. I have looked at the assembly code generated by optimizing compilers such as GCC and Clang and I have never thought "hey, this offset is computed twice, I could do better in hand-written assembly". I have had that thought for other constructs, thought (where potential aliasing that I knew not to happen in practice prevented the compiler from optimizing).

Comment: Why so much dereferencing? 

Checkout this SO Post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329096/c-pointers-vs-direct-member-access-for-structs

Comment: That's relative. The algorithms involved are O(N^2), with sets involving hundreds of thousands of objects, with a few complicated equations involving several members of each object. Ontop of that, this is for interactive simulations, so I'm doing this atleast 60 times a second with additional overhead from drawing and user input. This is currently the bottleneck, and will always be in this application.

Comment: @James Newman Read the assembly generated by your compiler. There is a minimal sequence of instructions to do what you want to do, and your compiler has **probably** found it. Complicating the situation can only move you **away** from this optimum.

Comment: @pascal-cuoq I thought the compiler might optimize this sort of thing decently well, but I have not checked. I'll try to do this.

Comment: @logancautrell My objects are in an array.

Comment: You can simulate reference syntax to some extent by doing `T *ptr = where_you_want_your_object;`  `#define myobject (*ptr)`. This is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting something that the compiler optimization does much better than you can do manually.  Also, C99,  does not have these referencing constructs the way you are attempting to define them in your example—specifically the C++ dereferencing declarations—if you're also getting really big  and deep, I suggest that you rethink your algorithm.  If you attempt to introduce a number of temporary variables and more memory around to do referencing you are going to make your life harder.

For instance if you look at:

```
struct some_struct {
        int a;
        struct {
                float f;
                double d;
        } s;
};

struct some_struct array[10000];

int process1(struct some_struct *r) {
#define R (*r)
        R.a+= 1;
        R.s.f = R.s.f/2;
        R.s.d = ( R.s.d + R.s.f ) * 2;
}

int process2(struct some_struct *r) {
        r->a+= 1;
        r->s.f = r->s.f/2;
        r->s.d = ( r->s.d + r->s.f ) * 2;
}

int doit() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(struct some_struct); i++ ) {
                struct some_struct *r = &array[i]; /* via reference */
                process1(r);
                process2(r);
        }
}
```

**process1 and process2 generate identical assembly outputs using gcc -O2 on x86_64 platform:**

```
        .file   "foo.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  process1
        .type   process1, @function
process1:
.LFB11:
        .cfi_startproc
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        addl    $1, (%rdi)
        mulss   8(%rdi), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
        unpcklps        %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtps2pd        %xmm0, %xmm0
        addsd   16(%rdi), %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 16(%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
        .size   process1, .-process1
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  process2
        .type   process2, @function
process2:
.LFB12:
        .cfi_startproc
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        addl    $1, (%rdi)
        mulss   8(%rdi), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
        unpcklps        %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtps2pd        %xmm0, %xmm0
        addsd   16(%rdi), %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 16(%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE12:
        .size   process2, .-process2
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  doit
        .type   doit, @function
doit:
.LFB13:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl    %edx, %edx

        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm2
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        leaq    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %rax
        addq    $1, %rdx
        leaq    array(,%rax,8), %rax
        movss   8(%rax), %xmm1
        addl    $2, (%rax)
        mulss   %xmm2, %xmm1
        cmpq    $10000, %rdx
        unpcklps        %xmm1, %xmm1
        cvtps2pd        %xmm1, %xmm0
        mulss   %xmm2, %xmm1
        addsd   16(%rax), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm1, 8(%rax)
        unpcklps        %xmm1, %xmm1
        cvtps2pd        %xmm1, %xmm1
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 16(%rax)
        jne     .L4
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE13:
        .size   doit, .-doit
        .comm   array,240000,32
        .section        .rodata.cst4,"aM",@progbits,4
        .align 4
.LC0:
        .long   1056964608
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.6.1"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Well, I suppose I'll just leave it alone. Your example doesn't seem to show what I'm trying to do, however. Your process 1 and 2 do the same thing...

I seem to have found references on the web that do it like I'm doing above, but with C++ as you've said.

I'll leave it a bit longer, then vote your answer since you've provided some information.

As a note, for a site that is so fixated on asking a specific question, I never seem to get a specific answer. I ask questions so I can be aware of all my options, and then compare their performance...

Comment: Hey James, I wasn't really sure what you were trying to do, I just gave an example that demonstrated referenced vs. dereferenced code, using same operations. Compilers go through a lot of nifty trouble to figure out structure references and memory math and do a great job at optimize out any redundancies. The best thing you can possibly do is make a simple implementation of your production code, and use the times utility to figure out how it performs. If you want to figure out the unit tests of how GCC optimizes a particular code segment, you can use the -S flag to generate the assembler.

Comment: Ahh, but it doesn't matter what assembly it produces if I only have one option available. ;)
Isn't (*R).a exactly the same as R->a?

Comment: heheh :-) sure... i meant that you can try various ways to process your data and look at the assembly outputs to see which one you like more.

Answer (score 3):

But.. there is no overhead to talk about!

What you are trying to do is actually adding overhead.

I think you need to learn that you should not work against a language, you should instead work with it; otherwise it becomes as if you are trying to push a square peg through a round hole with a hammer.

Comment: Well, I have no idea if it's possible in c or not. For all I know the language has a built construct that I'm unaware of for this particular operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea wouldn't save you anything. Pointers let you work with non-local memory. By definition, the struct in your array is far away, and you can't declare a local variable far away--that would be oxymoronic.

When you say `int &x = &myStruct.x;`, you're confusing two ideas:

- **The local variable**: you could rather easily

  ```
      int x = temp->x
      //work with x...
      temp->x = x
  ```

  the upside is that while you work with it, you're working with something close to you.
  The downside is the copying back and forth, but there really might be something to it.
- **The pointer**: The other way is to

  ```
     int *x = &temp->x
     //work with x, like you would a pointer
  ```

  but, this really isn't too helpful, because this isn't much different than using `temp->x` all over the place. (Except possibly in clarity). Think about arrays:
  Suppose you have the following code:

  ```
    int array[25];
    array[3] = array[2] + array[3];
    array[7] = array[3]*array[7] + array[3]<<7;
  ```

  You propose transforming it into this:

  ```
   int array[25]
   int *a = &array[3], *b=&array[2], *c=&array[7];
   *a = *b+*a;
   *c = (*a)*(*c) + *a<<7;
  ```

  It might be more readable, but the generated code may be similar and importantly, you mess with far-away memory *the exact same number of times*.

Comment: Depending on compiler optimization... If the compiler takes your code as is, then indexing into the array happens more in one example.

Comment: `gcc -O0` on SPARC shows 5 loads and 2 stores on the array in both versions.

Comment: `gcc -O2` shows only 3 loads, showing that the compiler is already good at preventing extraneous dereferencing.

Comment: I doubt -O0 is going to keep all optimizations from happening. Namely your indexing with constants in the example. *Sigh* You'd think my question was about how good compiler optimizations are... I know they're good.

Since the question, I have peeked at the disassembly of my code. With O2 I have a ton of repeated load->offset of the exact same addresses. -O3 is great. Hell, even the sqrt has function overhead in the -O0, and is optimized down to just a sqrtss in the -O3.
That's my point, however. We are relying completely on compiler optimizations.

Comment: [-O0](http://pastebin.com/qif7K5yh)

[-O3](http://pastebin.com/ZaKe20Hg)

Asm dumps of a _simple_ function in my project.

Comment: Also note that I already store pointers to the objects in the loops, so in the unoptimized that's just dereferencing, not any array indexing. It would be worst. Ofcourse either would _probably_ be optimized away in -03 or so.

Comment: You're missing my point. You either dereference on each use, or you use a local variable. When you see the compiler decreasing the number of loads and stores, it's because it's storing the result of the dereference in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the placement new operator, but that's C++, not C.

Other than that, I agree with the others -- leave it alone.